# How do I count the similar entries in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which has the following data

```
companyid    subscriptionid
1            21
1            23
2            89
4            99
4            101
```

I want to count how many times each unique company appears, how do I do this using t-sql?

So for example I want to see 1 = 2 times...but I dont mind if its in a table I dont need to print the data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT companyid, count(companyid) as TotalEntries
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY companyid
```

Comment: Okay this seems to be the most expressive statement as you are actually putting the name of the count item into the command so its quite obvious.

Comment: I think that CompanyId is not null here, but it is something to be aware of: `COUNT(columnName)` will only return values that are `NOT NULL`, where COUNT(*) or COUNT(1) will count all the records.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT companyid, COUNT(*) AS CompanyCount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY companyid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.CompanyId, COUNT(1)
FROM schema.table AS t
GROUP BY t.CompanyId
```